# Trying to make text fields start with a 0 value-swift

Tags: swift

I have a calculator app I'm working on where I want the fields to begin upon opening the app with a zero value, then they can enter a different value if they have one.  the reason is I have it to where the calculations will handle zeros in the equations, but if they don't enter a value in the field instead of printing text like" hey enter a number" I just want it to auto populate a zero in that field that they haven't entered anything for.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the initially value to 0. Whenever user remove all the text, you can re-set it to 0

```
let textField = <Your text field>
textField.text = "0"
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidEditing(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

@IBAction func textFieldDidEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text?.isEmpty == true {
        textField.text = "0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the text field in interface builder, select the attributes inspector in the utilities pane on the right side, then enter 0 in the text field. That's the value that will initially be in the text field when the app is run.

Comment: Man thank you.  that was exactly what I needed. hate to ask stupid questions but obviously just starting out in this so thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy I could help since I'm quite new to swift too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Following Step

**Step:-1** Set Default Value of textfield to 0 using the StoryBoard:

[image]

**Step:-2** Always Use `textfield.text` So that if user does not enter anything, than at-least it will get 0 in response.